# Install Release build of .ipa from iTunes for testing

Tags: app-store

I have just built a new version of my app and would like to test the final build (release) on my device before it is submitted to the App Store.

You see, I am making some changes to the app project via script and building automatically. I think there is a build related issue with current release that didn't appear during debug.

Is it possible to install an app on my device built using a release profile.

I fear not as there would be no reference to my device and if allowed it would mean a method of mass distribution outside the App Store.

Please say I am wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you are not wrong. :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but I think that is not possible. I used `Release` build on Jenkins with `Distribution` profile for AppStore. If I try to install the app I get a greyed out default icon (the one if you don't have an app icon) and if you tap on it it says something like

> YourAppName couldn't be installed. Please try it later again

This is on iOS 11. On iOS 10 the ipa isn't installed throug iTunes and it aborts at the half.

If you want to test on the device either use `Debug` build or `AdHoc`.